# I created a package to load a .png to rviz but every time I add an image visualization to rviz and change the image topic, rivz crashes

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "image_publisher");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  image_transport::ImageTransport it(n);
  image_transport::Publisher pub = it.advertise("/AS_logo", 1);
  cv::Mat image = cv::imread("/home/kamal/ROS_Work/1.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

 if( image.empty() )                      // Check for invalid input
{
    ROS_INFO("Could not open or find the image");
    return -1;
}


 sensor_msgs::ImagePtr msg = cv_bridge::CvImage(std_msgs::Header(), "bgr8", image).toImageMsg();

 ros::Rate loop_rate(1);
 while (n.ok()) {
   pub.publish(msg);
   ROS_INFO("ImageMsg Sent.");
   ROS_INFO("Subscribers: %d", pub.getNumSubscribers());
   ros::spinOnce();
   loop_rate.sleep();
 }

ros::spin();
return 0;
```

}

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279158/i-created-a-package-to-load-a-.png-to-rviz-but-every-time-i-add-an-image-visualization-to-rviz-and-change-the-image-topic,-rivz-crashes.-does-anyone-see-the-problem-?/) by [ixorim](https://answers.ros.org/users/33058/ixorim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-01-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) on 2018-01-08**:
Hi!

I just compiled your code and it worked perfect with this image: https://www.robotigniteacademy.com/static/img/course/structure.png

Could you run `rosrun rviz rviz --verbose` to see if there is any "error" log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you, I got it to work, it was the image size I had to resize it.

---

Originally posted by [ixorim](https://answers.ros.org/users/33058/ixorim/) with karma: 16 on 2018-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0